# Sort Parameter results in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

Good Morning, I am pretty new to report writing as well my needs are pretty basic. However I am running into a silly problem, that I can't seem to solve.

When I run a report the drop down list is out of alphabetical order. I would like it to be easier to the people to run the report to find whom they are looking for.

The code I have is as follows for the dataset.

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Staff'[StaffName], FILTER(VALUES('Staff'[StaffRole]), ('Staff'[StaffRole] = "Anesthesiologist")))
```

I was experimenting with the ORDER BY, but keep getting syntax errors. What I had was:

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Staff'[StaffName], FILTER(VALUES('Staff'[StaffRole]), ('Staff'[StaffRole] = "Anesthesiologist")))
ORDER BY
  Fields!StaffName.Value
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with DAX but I think you just need to change the ORDER BY clause like this.

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
'Staff'[StaffName], 
FILTER(VALUES('Staff'[StaffRole]), ('Staff'[StaffRole] = "Anesthesiologist")))
ORDER BY 'Staff'[StaffName]
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question. I really appreciate it. Have a great day!

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark the answer as accepted. That's the check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons. This help others with similar questions finding one that has an accepted answer.